# Cacheing images in flutter for no network connection

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to cache a network image that can be used later if there is no internet connection in flutter?

Comment: check for this package: extended network image in pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image

Answer (score 0):

you can use also a package like path_provider to save the image to the device's storage, and then use Image.file constructor to load the image from storage when offline.